# Is it possible to wrap Django code to ensure all database access for the ORM has "using" set by default?

Tags: django, django-orm, django-celery

I have a Django project that handles connections with multiple databases. I have a Database Router that handles the logic of which objects to store in a specific database which I easily use in my views, so no issue there at all.

For example:

```
class ClientDatabaseRouterMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, args, kwargs):
        if 'client_url' in kwargs:
            # kwargs = {key: value.lower() for key, value in kwargs.items()}
            thread_local.client_url = kwargs['client_url'].lower()

        else:
            if hasattr(thread_local, 'client_url'):
                del thread_local.client_url


class ClientDatabaseRouter:
    def _default_db(self):
        from django.conf import settings
        if hasattr(thread_local, 'client_url'):
            db = thread_local.client_url
            if db in settings.DATABASES:
                return db
        else:
            if settings.DEBUG:
                if hasattr(settings, 'DEBUG_CLIENT_DB'):
                    return settings.DEBUG_CLIENT_DB
            return None

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        instance = hints.pop('instance', None)
        if instance:
            if instance._state.db is not None:
                return instance._state.db

        if model._meta.app_label == 'client':
            return 'clients'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'django_celery_beat':
            return 'default'
        return self._default_db()

    db_for_write = db_for_read

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return obj1._state.db == obj2._state.db

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if db == 'default':
            return app_label == 'django_celery_beat'

        if not app_label == 'client':
            if db == 'clients':
                return False
        else:
            return db == 'clients'

        return None
```

However, I also use Celery and naturally I am storing expensive operations in those tasks. The issue is that no matter what I seem to do I have to pass the `using` variable into my objects as it is a separate process and it can't use my Router: such as:

`my_thing.objects.using('alias').create(...)`

This isn't a huge issue, but it is very annoying for development as I can run the task locally without `using=''` and it works, but when I push up to production, the task fails if I forget `using=''` anywhere... I guess the communication with Docker and my 3rd party DB is different in production than local instances in dev, but either way it is annoying.

Ideally what I want is some type of wrapping block that I can surround my task code in a block that forces each transaction with the ORM to use a specific alias. Something like `with transaction.atomic():` would be great in my instance, for example:

```
with database_alias as 'my_custom_alias':
    my_thing.objects.create(...) 
    # and this essentially acts as my_thing.objects.using('my_custom_alias').create(...)
```

Is this possible? I can't seem to work out a way to do it...

Comment: Where does `client_url` come from? Is there a separate instance running for each client?

Comment: It is a URL param, not a separate instance, but that param is what dictates which backend DB to use. The client_url essentially acts as the alias to the DB constructed in settings.